# Copy Vector of Pointers gives Seg Fault. (C++)

Tags: c++, pointers, vector, segmentation-fault

I am having a strange problem. I am trying to write a copy constructor for my class which contains an integer and a vector of pointers which point to other objects of the same class.

```
class A {

    private:
        int id;
        std::vector<A*> relatedObjects;
}
```

In the main function, I am creating an object of class A using the default constructor. And then two more A objects allocated dynamically

```
A master;
A* slave1 = new A;
A* slave2 = new A;
```

I am then adding the two slave objects to the vector using a public function which just pushes the pointers to the vector.

```
addSlave(A* slave) {

    this->relatedObjects.push_back(slave);
}
```

Now the problem that I am having is when I want to make a copy of master from the main function. I get a segfault when trying to copy the vector of pointers. I am trying to do a shallow copy because I want the new object to reference the same slave objects and not an isolated copy. My copy constructor is as follows:

```
A::A(const A& orig) {

    this->id = orig.id;
    this->relatedObjects = orig.relatedObjects;
}
```

I have also tried iterating through the vector copying the pointers one by one, but that still results in the same segfault. According to the documentation on vectors, the "=" operator "Assigns a copy of vector x as the new content for the vector object", in this case meaning copy the pointers to the new vector object. This is what I want.

I am unsure why I am getting this problem, and I am sure that this is the reason behind the seg fault as when the vector copy is commented out, the seg fault disappears. If anybody could help with this, I would be very grateful.

Thank you.

Comment: Does `A` have a non-trivial destructor?

Comment: Please construct a [**minimal** test-case](http://sscce.org).

Comment: Thank you @D.Shawley I did have a non-trivial destructor where I was deleting the objects pointed to in this array. I commented it out to use the default destructor, and all problems were solved. Now that you point it out, I may not need this destructor in the end.

Comment: @apatrick - NP. Seg faults are commonly caused by deleting something that you have a pointer to somewhere else.  You might want to consider using `shared_ptr<>` whenever you start having collections of pointers.

Comment: You may not need the copy constructor either: as is, it doesn't do any better than the one that would be *automatically* generated by the compiler *if you simply didn't bother writing it*. In fact, it's *worse* than what the compiler would generate: the compiler would use member initializers, not assignment.

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes Right, that's what I ended up doing. Thanks for your help.